# Gnome/Mate programs keep copies of seen pictures - when are those deleted?

Tags: linux, gnome, privacy, cache, mate

Mate's file manager Caja stores copies of almost every picture file shown to the user (preview thumbnails) in the user's home directory. So does Gnome's image viewer "Eye of Gnome" (eog) for every opened picture.

On one computer, the cache directory contained files that were a year old. It usually doesn't make a lot of sense to keep cached contents for months, and it's a waste of disk space. Also, it may be a major privacy issue if the user account is used by more than one person.

When does Gnome/Mate delete these cached copies automatically, does it happen after a certain amount of time or after a certain number of reboots?

Caja and eog are just two examples, they both seem to use `~/.cache/thumbnails`. What about other commonly used file managers and image viewers like KDE's Dolphin and Gwenview? Do these keep copies of everything as well and if so, when do they delete them?

Also, are there standard tools to clear the cache manually (before it's cleared automatically)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of cleanup tools for Linux, such as [BleachBit](http://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux). [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) makes access to Ubuntu's system Janitor convenient, too. For some others, see [OMG!Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/what-is-the-best-ubuntu-system-cleaner-you-decide-poll).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the main question.